# Initialize numpy array in two dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

So, if I want a numpy array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] (or any other vector with, say 7 elements) which has the dimension (7,1) and not (7,), is there anyway to do that when I create it, instead of writing
`t=np.expand_dims(np.array(range(7)),axis=1)` ?

Comment: Essentially the same, but shorter : `np.arange(7)[:,None]`? Starting with `range(7)`, you need to expand dims somehow.

Comment: But say you have a vector [20,13,0,13,12,-3,9], it does not work. 
I find it odd that numpy creates these "dimensionless" vectors as default.

Comment: `np.array(range(7)).reshape((7,1))` or `np.array([list(range(7))]).T` is the best I can think of.

Comment: it seems like you need to add som extra methods/functions to do it then...

Comment: `np.arange(7)` isn't dimensionless.  It is 1d,  We don't need 2d to represent a list of 7 numbers.

Comment: `np.atleast_2d`, and `np.array(..., ndmin=2)` are two builtin tools for starting with 2d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of is

```
i = range(7)

j = np.array(i)[:, None]
```

A slightly shorter way is:

```
j = np.atleast_2d(i).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Just transpose it

```
x = np.array([range(7)]).T
```